2D PNG images analysis using textureFeatures/Matlab Medical Imaging Toolbox
I am trying to get the GLCM Properties from an image using Matlab Medical Imaging Toolbox. I know how to do it with the graycoprops but as the Medical Imaging Toolbox allows also to examine GLRLM, GLSZM, GLDZM, NGTDM and NGLDM (using textureFeatures), I find it very interesting
As textureFeatures can only read DICOM files I saved my file to this format but I have no idea if it is possible to convert it to Radiomics object and move forward with the analysis. Any idea if it can be done and how?
Code:
jpgI = imread('https://www.mathworks.com/help/examples/medical/win64/ComputeTextureFeaturesForComputedTomographyCTImageExample_01.png');
 
dicomwrite(jpgI,"E:/testFile.dcm");
medImg = medicalImage("E:/testFile.dcm");
dicomStats = textureFeatures(medImg ,Type="GLCM",SubType="2D")

